# Upgrading firmware for a PERCH700 RAID card on an old Dell Studio XPS 9100 desktop, running CentOS 7.5

Tags: raid, centos7, dell-perc, firmware

I run a home media server on an older Dell XPS studio 9100 desktop with a Dell PERC H700 RAID card.

I've been trying to upgrade firmware on the perc card and I haven't been able to, always get:

```
[root@centos Dell]# ./SAS-RAID_Firmware_9FVJ2_LN_12.10.7-0001_A13.BIN 
Collecting inventory...
....Can't open IPMI device
.............
Running validation...
This Update Package is not compatible with your system configuration.
[root@centos Dell]#
```

I've downloaded packages from here -> http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=9fvj2

Details on the system:

```
[root@centos ~]# omreport storage controller | grep -v 'Not Applicable'
 Controller  PERC H700 Integrated(Embedded)

Controller
ID                                            : 0
Status                                        : Non-Critical
Name                                          : PERC H700 Integrated
Slot ID                                       : Embedded
State                                         : Degraded
Firmware Version                              : 12.10.6-0001
Minimum Required Firmware Version             : 12.10.7-0001
Driver Version                                : 07.702.06.00-rh2
Number of Connectors                          : 2
Rebuild Rate                                  : 30%
BGI Rate                                      : 30%
Check Consistency Rate                        : 30%
Reconstruct Rate                              : 30%
Cache Memory Size                             : 512 MB
Patrol Read Mode                              : Auto
Patrol Read State                             : Stopped
Patrol Read Rate                              : 30%
Patrol Read Iterations                        : 1
Abort Check Consistency on Error              : Disabled
Allow Revertible Hot Spare and Replace Member : Enabled
Auto Replace Member on Predictive Failure     : Disabled
Persistent Hot Spare                          : Disabled
Encryption Capable                            : Yes
Encryption Key Present                        : No
Encryption Mode                               : None
Spin Down Unconfigured Drives                 : Disabled
Spin Down Hot Spares                          : Disabled
T10 Protection Information Capable            : No

[root@centos ~]#
```

Comment: Try to do it via `PERCCLI Install`. Also this utility can show real hardware and firmware versions.

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy. you mean this? 

Looked into .BIN/ file and found script parameters to extract actual binary rom file. 

    `[root@centos Dell]# ./SAS-RAID_Firmware_2948G_LN_12.10.7-0001_A13_02.BIN --extract /tmp/
    Successfully extracted to /tmp/
    [root@centos Dell]#
    
    [root@centos Dell]# ll /tmp/payload/
    total 3840
    -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 3932160 May 30 11:50 FW4651A.rom
    [root@centos Dell]#`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for suggestions. Here is solution for others coming after me.

- Downloaded firmware from link above, on original post. File has a `.BIN` extension but it's a bash script with an inline binary file.
- You can extract binary file from the `.BIN` file

  ```
  [root@centos ~]# ./SAS-RAID_Firmware_9FVJ2_LN_12.10.7-0001_A13.BIN --extract /tmp/
  [root@centos ~]# ll /tmp/payload/FW4651I.rom
  ```
- Flashed firmware, using `perccli` utility and rebooted.

  ```
  [root@centos ~]# perccli64 /c0 download file=/tmp/payload/FW4651I.rom
  ```
- Now I've got latest firmware version

  ```
  [root@centos ~]# omreport storage controller | grep -v 'Not Applicable'
  Controller  PERC H700 Integrated(Embedded)

  Controller
  ID                                            : 0
  Status                                        : Ok
  Name                                          : PERC H700 Integrated
  Slot ID                                       : Embedded
  State                                         : Ready
  Firmware Version                              : 12.10.7-0001
  Driver Version                                : 07.702.06.00-rh2
  Number of Connectors                          : 2
  Rebuild Rate                                  : 30%
  BGI Rate                                      : 30%
  Check Consistency Rate                        : 30%
  Reconstruct Rate                              : 30%
  Cache Memory Size                             : 512 MB
  Patrol Read Mode                              : Auto
  Patrol Read State                             : Stopped
  Patrol Read Rate                              : 30%
  Patrol Read Iterations                        : 1
  Abort Check Consistency on Error              : Disabled
  Allow Revertible Hot Spare and Replace Member : Enabled
  Auto Replace Member on Predictive Failure     : Disabled
  Persistent Hot Spare                          : Disabled
  Encryption Capable                            : Yes
  Encryption Key Present                        : No
  Encryption Mode                               : None
  Spin Down Unconfigured Drives                 : Disabled
  Spin Down Hot Spares                          : Disabled
  T10 Protection Information Capable            : No

  [root@centos ~]# /opt/MegaRAID/perccli/perccli64 /c0 show | grep 'FW Package Build'
  FW Package Build = 12.10.7-0001
  ```

Comment: Nicely done. Good "answer" using the info you found.

Answer (score 1):

That update package/tool only supports Enterprise server/storage platforms. You would need to extract the firmware file (FW4651I.rom) and use something like sas2flash from LSI/Broadcom to flash it.